# If Seiya died at the end of the "Hades", how can he fight as Gold Saint in "Saint Seiya Omega"?

Tags: saint-seiya

Saint Seiya died at the end of Hades. Yet, in *Saint Seiya Omega*, I saw him fight as Sagittarius.

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_Seiya#In_other_media) (emphasis mine):

> In *Saint Seiya Omega* however the story branches out the Hades Chapter in a different way. Seiya is shown in several flashbacks as **having recovered**, and still serving Athena, as Saori Kido, as the Sagittarius Gold Saint this time, revered as a legend and a source of inspiration to whom the newest Pegasus, Kōga, looks at hoping to match his prowess and legendary deeds.

So, short answer, it's either a retcon or an alternate continuity depending on your point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Seiya does not die and it is proved in Saint Seiya next dimension when Saori said he only had 3 more days of life and needed to destroy Hades sword before it got to Seiya hart.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, *Omega* is an alternate timeline and it wasn’t true. But *Next Dimension* still did prove him to be the next generation Sagittarius saint, but he is still fainting right now.

Comment: You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to include evidence that _Saint Seiya Omega_ takes place in an alternate timeline from _Saint Seiya: The Hades Chapter_.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We prefer people not to answer in-character, but to refer to facts that can be seen in the show or related works.  You might want to take the [tour].